# Significantly lower accuracy while using class_weight for imbalanced dataset in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sentiment-analysis

I have rather unintuitive problem. I am doing the sentiment analysis on Amazon Book reviews and the data set is heavily imbalanced. Positive reviews are almost 10 times the negative reviews, accuracy for both training and testing are around 90% (with imbalanced dataset). However, when I try to balance the dataset with the help of `class_weight = {0:10 , 1:1}` both training and testing accuracy drops to around 65%. Again if I do `class_weight = {0:1 , 1:10}` accuracy booms again, so apparently I am setting the `class_weight` wrong but as I understood because the number of positive reviews(1) are 10 times the number of negative reviews(0), shouldn't the `class_weight` be set as {0:10 , 1:1} ?

This is how I classify training and testing data:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(sequences,labels, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42)
```

This is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(32, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=320, class_weight = {0:1 , 1:10})
```

Comment: Note that one of the things the model learns is 'how probable' a sample is to be 0 or 1, even without seeing the sample. When you use class weights like that you actually change the model.

Answer (score 3):

Of course if you do not balance the loss you'll get better accuracy than if you balance it. Actually this is the reason for balancing. Otherwise the model that predict only positive class for all reviews will give you 90% accuracy. But this model is useless. Accuracy is generally bad metric for such strongly unbalanced datasets. Use F1 instead and you'll see that unbalanced model gives much worse F1.

Answer (score 0):

Setting higher class weight for a class with lower frequency in a data set is the right approach. More than Accuracy you can look at other more [useful metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values) like Precision, Recall, F1 score, auc_roc score (Concordance), Confusion matrix to actually understand what the model is learning.

Comment: okay but I want to understand about the significantly lower accuracy with class_weight

Comment: Lower accuracy because of multiple reasons. Change your model architecture, data preprocessing, model hyper parameters, etc.